# Set LLVM assembly output syntax with C++ API

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to find a way to set the assembly syntax that LLVM outputs (for x86 in particular).  Following the [Compiling to Object Code](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl08.html#emit-object-code) section of the Kaleidoscope tutorial, I'm outputting assembly files with

```
TargetMachine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass, dest, nullptr, llvm::CGFT_AssemblyFile))
```

But there's no option to set the output syntax.

`llc` has the command line option `--x86-asm-syntax` with which you can set the output assembly syntax (for x86), so I'm sure there must be a way to do it.

So is there a way this can be done through LLVM's C++ API?

Comment: I have no setup to test this, but looking at the code that creates `TargetMachine`, the Opt is made of `TargetOptions`, which [apparently](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1TargetOptions.html) includes things like AssemblyLanguage.  That's where I'd start, anyway.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That seems like a possible solution, but LLVM 10 doesn't seem to have that. Searching for `AssemblyLanguage` (or similar) in the llvm include directory also returns nothing.

Comment: It's [apparently](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MCTargetOptions.html) supposed to be in "llvm/MC/MCTargetOptions.h", but I've no idea when it may have been added.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Looking on github, it was added in LLVM 11, which is supposed to be coming out soon.  Mind making this into an answer?

Comment: On a deeper dive into the doxygen reference,  `AssemblyLanguage` is only referenced [here](https://llvm.org/doxygen/X86MCTargetDesc_8cpp_source.html#l00318) where it only checks if it's equal to `"masm"`, so this may not be what I'm looking for after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few things I found out by reading the LLVM source:

- The output assembly syntax is controlled by the [`AssemblyDialect`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MCAsmInfo.html#aaab4eaa2f4de9c0d12606c176dd9d738) member in `llvm::MCAsmInfo`.  For x86 the derived classes of `llvm::MCAsmInfo` can be found in [`X86MCAsmInfo.h`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/Target/X86/MCTargetDesc/X86MCAsmInfo.h) and [`X86MCAsmInfo.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/Target/X86/MCTargetDesc/X86MCAsmInfo.cpp).
- The member `AssemblyDialect` is initialized to the value of `AsmWriterFlavor`, which is set by the command line option `x86-asm-syntax`.

As far as I could tell `AssemblyDialect` isn't referenced anywhere else in the code base, so the only way to set it is by the `x86-asm-syntax` flag.  For that you can use `llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions`. Minimal example for setting the assembly syntax to intel:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <llvm/Support/CommandLine.h>

void set_asm_syntax_to_intel()
{
    char const *args[] = { "some-exe-name", "--x86-asm-syntax=intel" };
    auto const res = llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(std::size(args), args);
    assert(res);
}
```